# Javascript Module Pattern Memory Footprint and Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, memory

I am using the Javascript Module Pattern to try and implement C# enumeration-like functionality. I have two ways that I am currently thinking about implementing this functionality but I do not understand all the benefits or advantages of one way versus the other.

Here is implementation 1:

```
var MyApp = (function (app) {

    // Private Variable
    var enums = {
        ActionStatus: {
            New: 1,
            Open: 2,
            Closed: 3
        }
    };

    // Public Method
    app.getEnum = function (path) {
        var value = enums;            
        var properties = path.split('.');
        for (var i = 0, len = properties.length; i < len; ++i) {
            value = value[properties[i]];
        }
        return value;
    };

    return app;

})(MyApp || {});

// Example usage
var status = MyApp.getEnum("ActionStatus.Open");
```

And now implementation 2:

```
var MyApp = (function (app) {

    // Public Property
    app.Enums = {
        ActionStatus: {
            New: 1,
            Open: 2,
            Closed: 3
        }
    };

    return app;

})(MyApp || {});

// Example usage
var status = MyApp.Enums.ActionStatus.Open;
```

The main difference is in using a "private" variable vs a "public" property to store the enums. I would think implementation 1 is a little slower but I was not sure if keeping the enums as "private" reduced the memory usage. Can anyone explain the difference in memory footprint and performance for the two (if any)? Any other suggestions/advice are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...but I was not sure if keeping the enums as "private" reduced the memory usage

The opposite, if anything: You still have to have the enums object, *and* you have to have a function to access it.

In terms of speed, I wouldn't worry about it. The added function call won't make any real difference (I [looked into it](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html) when worried about using the new `forEach` and such, and even on IE6 with its *massively* slow JS engine, it just doesn't matter).

In a couple of years, you'll probably be able to have the best of both worlds: Enums that are read-only, thanks to ECMAScript5's [`Object.defineProperties`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.7) feature:

```
var Enums = Object.defineProperties({}, {
    ActionStatus: {
        value: Object.defineProperties({}, {
            New:    {value: 1},
            Open:   {value: 2},
            Closed: {value: 3}
        })
    }
});

// Usage
var n = Enums.ActionStatus.New; // 1
```

By default, properties created with `defineProperties` are *read-only*.

In fact, you can basically have that now if you add an ES5 "shim" to create `Object.defineProperties` on browsers that don't yet have it natively. The "shimmed" version would create read-write properties, since only the natively-supported version can really create read-only properties, but you can write the code now and know that it will work as you like on modern browsers (about half of all web surfers currently have them) while still working, just with less robustness, on less-modern ones.

And of course, EMCAScript6 may take things further, but that's still a future thing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and for the ES5 info. Do you know in terms of browser memory management how implementation 1 stores its private variable vs implementation 2's storing of its public property? I tried to profile the memory consumption but all I could find out was that implementation 2 made MyApp's object size larger while implementation 1 did not. But I know implementation 1 has to store the reference to the private variable somewhere.

Comment: @steve_ut: It's stored in something called (deep breath) the *variable binding object* of the *execution context* of the call to the anonymous function you're using to create the object. *(whew)* :-) That's the [ES5 spec](http://es5.github.com) terminology ([canonical link](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)). Every call to a function gets a variable binding object, which contains the args to the function, its local vars, and a few other things as properties. Description with older terminology here *[Closures are not complicated](http://goo.gl/OzIQY)*.

Comment: @steve_ut: Or actually, to be more correct, it's stored in the general memory pool and the variable binding object has a reference to it. That's also the more correct way to look at your `MyApp` object; whatever tool you're using to map the size of `MyApp` is giving you some simplified information there. JavaScript is all about objects in the memory pool with references to each other. The `MyApp` object from implementation 2 doesn't actually *contain* the object referenced by `app.Enums` any more than implementation 1 does.