# How much memory is allocated when using the Module Pattern?

Tags: javascript

I want to refactor Snippet 1 to Snippet 2.  I don't think performance is quite an issue here considering the size, but I wanted to understand what was going on as far as memory use goes regarding this refactor to the module pattern.

The module pattern ensures that I only pull in this data from the DOM once which is what I want and it also forms a mini-registry pattern in that the data is private.

Both snippets have been tested and basically work.

**Snippet 1** // Replace SUniverisals w/ SU

```
var SUniversals = function () {
    // Pull from Server
    this.universals.path = document.getElementById('universals').getAttribute('data-path');
    this.universals.load = document.getElementById('universals').getAttribute('data-load');
    // Set Manually
    this.universals.debug = false;
};
SUniversals.prototype.universals = {};
SUniversals.prototype.get = function( key ) {
    return this.universals[ key ];
};
SUniversals.prototype.set = function( key, value ) {
    this.universals[ key ] = value;
};
```

**Snippet 2**

```
var SU = ( function () 
{
    // private SU.get('load');
    var universals = {};
        universals.path = document.getElementById('universals').getAttribute('data-path');
        universals.load = document.getElementById('universals').getAttribute('data-load');
        universals.debug = false;
    // pubulic
    var publik = {};
        publik.get = function( key )
        {
            return universals[ key ];
        };
        publik.set = function( key, value )
        {
            universals[ key ] = value;
        };
        return publik;
}());
```

Comment: *"I read on SO that Self Executing functions pull in outside memory to create a closure that may/may not result in a performance hit."* Whether a function is self-executing has precisely zero effect on what it closes over. The memory impact of closures is all about what's in scope where they're defined, and whether anything keeps a reference to them or functions (closures) created within them. More: *[Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)*.

Comment: *"I reference nothing outside of the SU function."* It's the other way around: What references to the contents of the `SU` function are maintained? And in your Snipppet 2, the answer is, all of it -- because you have a variable, `SU`, that points to it.

Comment: @ Hiro: No, there are no *copies*. There are **references**. Read the link.

Comment: @ Hiro: *"2008...hope that is still relevant"* Nothing signficant has changed. The terminology used in the ES5 spec is a bit different from the ES3 terminology used in the article, but the concepts are completely unchanged.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Module Pattern Memory Footprint and Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418178/javascript-module-pattern-memory-footprint-and-performance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things which are different. Snippet 2 is essentially creating a singleton. Snippet 1 can be looked at like a 'class'.  You can create multiple instances/objects of 'SUniversals' and do different things with them.

Actually, snippet 1 is more efficient in terms of memory. By adding to the object's prototype, you essentially will have only 1 copy of each function irrespective of the number of objects you create. The module pattern will create separate entities.

Comment: oops. thanks for fixing the typo.Also,another thing to note is, using the 'prototype' based approach may give you better performance if you are creating like hundreds of objects. But it requires a pretty good understanding of 'this' to make it work correctly. As my colleague used to say, you don't debug 'this', 'this' debugs you.

Comment: If you understand 'this', no need to debug it :-)

Comment: And it's worth noting that the singleton (module/namespace) pattern and various constructor/class-like patterns are not mutually exclusive. In large volume js, organised into modules, it's not at all uncommon to find constructors etc within the singeltons.

Comment: Thanks for info. However, As Modular pattern creates memory leaks, how that would be faster than prototyping pattern. Please check this. http://jsperf.com/modular-patter-vs-prototyping

Answer (score 1):

Not enough to worry about ;-)

Seriously, the only thing you need to worry about with the module pattern is creating memory leaks; by itself the pattern uses basically nothing.

Comment: Well, the module pattern *is* an idiom.  Look at jQuery: they use it (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js).  And Backbone as well (http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js).  So does pretty much every major Javscript library.  Heck, even Crockford's JSON implementation (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) uses it.